# xamarin studio, ios, save data between launches

Tags: c#, android-studio, xamarin

Is there a some analog in xamarin (ios) of shared preferences in android studio to save data between launches?

Or the best way to do this - write in file and read when its needed?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var webClient = new WebClient();

        var url = new Uri("some_url");

        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var text = e.Result;
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string localFilename = "downloaded.txt";
            string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
            File.WriteAllText(localPath, text);

            long miliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

            NSUserDefaults.StandartUserDefaults.setBool(true, "Boolean"); //the name 'NSUserDefaults' does not exist in the current context - why?


            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);

        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS, you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/user-defaults/) to store configuration and preferences data

```
// Get Shared User Defaults
var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

// Save value
plist.SetString(userName, "UserName");

// Sync changes to database
plist.Synchronize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NSUserDefaults.

Write a string to: `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, key);`
Read a string from: `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(key);`